# Sliding in a fixed element using CSS3 transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have an element with fixed position and auto width (must have auto width) that should slide-in from the left.

I've defined two states for it: *hidden* and *visible*. When visible it should be positioned on the left side of the window, when hidden it should be just outside of view.

#### Visible state

```
left: 0;
/* right: auto; */
```

#### Hidden state

```
right: 100%;
/* left: -element auto width */
```

Both of these states display ok when transition is static without any animation.

### Alternative 1: CSS3 transforms

I've also tried using CSS3 transforms, which works, but I'm afraid of cross browser differences. When transitions are not supported transition would automatically fall back to static change, but if I use CSS3 transforms, there's no direct fall-back. It has to be explicitly defined.

This is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zzhdv/2/) of the effect by using CSS3 transitions **and transforms**. As you can see, the width of the left bar is wide as much as it has to be and it slides just beyond the left edge when going into *hidden* state.

### Alternative 2: Collapsing element width

This could somehow be done by manipulating element width (while also using max/min width to support auto width), but the problem with this is that content doesn't move. It's apparent that element width is being manipulated.
We have to move the element including its content.

### Question

Is there any way to avoid CSS3 tranforms while also satisfying following rules:

- width **must** be auto
- when visible it's positioned on the left window edge
- when hidden it's positioned just outside of left edge

Comment: Toggle between `left:-100%` and `left:0px;` with javascript

Comment: @Zeaklous: The same thing could be done without Javascript. But -100% is **not ok** as that moves the element beyond window edge.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask: You want to *slide* the element using CSS only, but you don't want to use transitions/transforms, because of some older browsers? Why don't you use a JavaScript fallback, that animates the said CSS property for browsers, that don't support transitions? Or maybe I misinterpret your question.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I was basing my comment on "when hidden it's positioned just outside of left edge"

Comment: @insertusernamehere: I want to use transitions, but not transforms. Browsers that don't support transitions will fallback to non-animated state change. But if I use transforms there won't be no fallback by design. Am I making myself clear enough?

Comment: @Zeaklous: -100% will take width of the window and not element itself so it will be positioned one scree away out of view if you know what I mean...

Comment: @RobertKoritnik You are correct but it will make a smooth transition easy

Comment: Use "@keyframe" rules...
http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Comment: I've added a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zzhdv/2/) that works as expected on browsers that support CSS3 transitions and transforms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to wrap your element into another div:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="element">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        <br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        <br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae explicabo!
    </div>
</div>
```

And `#element` transitions between `left: 0%` and `left: -100%`.

Live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgzcI

Comment: Works exactly as intended without transforms.

Comment: In this example the wrapper div is always visible, and since its position is fixed it covers other content on the page. Maybe need to hide and show the wrapper when toggling as well or something?...

Comment: Thanks so much for this example! Has really helped me understand CSS Transitions using fixed elements :D